# How to apply custom filter in second recyclerview depending upon the selection in first recyclerview?

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview

I am using the custom filter ,and passing the constraint to filter from adapter ,In this scenario I want to pass the constraint to another adapter now how do I communicate between two different adapters ?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem which is very easily handled if you follow MVP design in your code.

Let me assume some class names, since you have not mentioned any. Lets say that you have two adapters - `adapter1` and `adapter2`, inside `fragment1` and `fragment2`. Let us assume the fragments are added in the activity called `MainActivity`

Now, you should use interfaces being implemented for callbacks from adapters and fragments. So, `Fragment1` implements the `adapter1CallbackInterface` and `fragment2` implements `adapter2CallbackInterface`. Similarly `MainActivity` implements the `fragment1CallackInterface`. This takes care of the backward communication. Now, the adapters and fragment have public methods for forward communication.

So, whenever someone selects a filter in your `adapter1`, the `callflow` would be :

> `adapter1` -> `adapter1CallbackInterface` -> `fragment1CallbackInterface` -> `fragment2PublicMethod` -> `adapter2PublicMethod`

Needless to say, if the `adapter1` and `adapter2` are directly included in your activity, the `fragment1Callback` and `fragment2PublicMethod` can be ignored

Comment: Use customized names wherever needed

Comment: thanks :),I tried implementing the custom callback interface but it was giving me null pointer exception , so I found Otto event bus library